# Swift - How to multiply value from UITextField

Tags: uitextfield, swift

```
@IBOutlet weak var labelLabel: UILabel
@IBOutlet weak var textFieldField: UITextField
@IBAction func buttonButton(sender: AnyObject) {

   var conversionRate = 7

        self.labelLabel.text = self.textFieldField.text // Here I'm trying to multiply textFieldField by 7 (conversionRate)

        textFieldField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
```

Hello, I want to multiply a value from UITextField by 7. Can someone help me?
I've tried everything. .toInt(), intValue() and nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work with `.toInt()`:

```
if let number = self.textFieldField.text?.toInt() {
  self.labelLabel.text = "\(number * conversionRate)"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
    var conversionRate = 7;
    var value = self.nameLbl.text.toInt();
    value = value!*conversionRate;
    self.nameLbl.text = NSString(format:"%d",value!)as String;
```

**OR**

```
    var conversionRate = 7;
    var value : Int = self.nameLbl.text.toInt()!;
    value = value*conversionRate;
    self.nameLbl.text = String(value);
```

OR

```
    var conversionRate = 7;
    if let number = nameLbl.text?.toInt() {
        self.nameLbl.text = "\(number * conversionRate)"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    let a = textFieldField.text
    let conversionRate = 7
    let b = Int(a!)! * conversionRate //use Double(a!)! instead of Int(a!)! if your are using a floating point value for "conversionRate" variable.
    labelLabel.text = ("\(b)")
```

Happy coding!

Comment: Please add some explanation to the answer along with the code that would be very helpful.