# Multiplying ints in swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I am new to swift and iOS programming and learning slowly here. So I have:

```
@IBOutlet weak var timeEntered: UITextField!



@IBAction func countDown(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        var total = timeEntered.text.toInt()

        total = total *7


    }
```

The line `total = total *7` gives me the error **"Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by a ;"**

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24625176/swift-how-to-multiply-value-from-uitextfield) that you should do ( I don't know why but...)

```
total = total! *7
```

And still I get the same error. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: did you try adding semicolon after the declaration? Also, consider using `var total = 7 * timeEntered.text.toInt()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you must separate the '*' and the '7'. Try this `total = total * 7`

Comment: This is absolutely ridiculous! It works but I mean come on! Thanks for the answer mate. Appreciate the help. Would you also happen to know why the ! has to be used?

Comment: ! is used to 'unwrap' an optional value in Swift. Here's a great introduction about optionals in Swift: https://medium.com/@rrridges/swift-optionals-a10dcfd8aab5

Comment: Thank you! Have a great NY!

Comment: @user3369038 It's quite obvious when you think about it. you are sending `toInt()` to a string. The string may not be convertible to an Int. So `toInt()` returns an optional. the `!` is forcibly unwrapping the optional; in essence you are saying, I know this will not fail, so just unwrap the answer. Personally, you should be doing this with conditional unwrapping and gracefully handling any errors. This is why you have the `!`. Not so ridiculous is it?

Comment: After reading above...absolutely not! Haha! Thank you very much :) Btw the ridiculous part was aimed at the space. Surely the compiler must be able to tell that *7 and * 7 is the same thing?!

Answer (score 1):

In Swift, operators like "*" must have either *no space* on either side of the operator, or white space on both sides of the operator.

That forces you to avoid ugliness like your

```
total = total *7
```

Write it nicely. Either of these:

```
total = total * 7
total = total*7
```

Now this:

```
total = total! *7
```

That's just grabbing around in the dark without any idea what you are doing. That's no way how to program. You must know *why*. How can you ever be sure what your code does when you don't know the why's?

Comment: There is a good reason for the `!` It's because `toInt()` might fail, so it returns an optional. Personally I'd go for conditional unwrapping, but there is a good reason for the exclamation point. And to be fair to the OP, he is asking __why__ it works with `!`.